# Dojox.mobile Search Bar

Tags: iphone, web-applications, dojo

Hy people,

i need a search-element for iphone in HTML with css.  i use dojo, but this have no element for this. can anyone post me complete example or a link to an example?

thank in advance

dimi

Answer (score 0):

There is a search element:

dojox.mobile.SearchBox
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/SearchBox